# What is the definition of Riemann surface of an algebraic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-curves

What does it mean by the Riemann Surface of a function $y=\sqrt{x^3}$? I saw how to use the cut and glue method to obtain a sphere where $y=\sqrt{x}$ can be defined. But I was not clear in what sense does it mean by a Riemann surface of a function. can anyone help me with the definition?

Using the same method, I found out the Riemann surface of $y=\sqrt{x^3}$ is a sphere, which seems strange since the algebraic curve $\text{Spec}\ k[x,y]/(x^3-y^2)$ is singular.

Comment: Note that your two curves are birationally equivalent.

Comment: Yes, but what does it mean by the riemann surface of $x\sqrt{x}$?